# UIView Animation Cancel

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, touch

I want to make a UIView go off the screen upon a touch and come back **after a small delay** after touch up.  So far:

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == myMainView)
    {
    [disappearingView.layer removeAllAnimations];   
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.7
          initialSpringVelocity:0.2
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^
     {
        disappearingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);

     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];

    }
}

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == myMainView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:1
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.7
          initialSpringVelocity:0.2
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^
     {
        disappearingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];

    }
}
```

Above code works fine so far.  However, if the user lift the finger up and touch down again before the 1 second delay expires, disappearing view still comes back, even with the touch down.  If you touch down and up randomly, animation is very inconsistent.

I want view to come back only after 1 second and there are no touches at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag in `touchesBegan` and clear it again in `touchesEnded`.  In your animation block for `touchesEnded`, check the flag and do not rescale to (1,1) if the flag is set.  That way if you get a second touch after the first has ended but before the animation completes, it will not come back.

Comment: I am in the process of trying this.  What's the best practice on the DELAY.  Should I do it by delaying animation ? or do [self performSelector:@selector(touchUpAnimations) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; ?

Comment: I don't think there's a big difference.  My preference would be to let the animation do the delay (as you currently do), but doing it the other way would avoid animating "doing nothing" if another touch has occurred.